# Is there a way to keep indexing nested dictionaries until you find a string value?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I'm working with a dict. It has some nested dicts. It looks like this:

As you can see, `education` and `experience` have nested dicts. `skills`, `industry` and `summary` are just keys with values.

```
{
  "education": [
    {
      "start": "1991",
      "major": "Human Resources"
    },
    {
      "start": "1984",
      "major": "Chemistry"
    }
  ],
  "skills": [
    "AML",
    "Relationship Management",
    "Team Management"
  ],
  "industry": "Banking",
  "experience": [
    {
      "org": "Standard Chartered Bank",
      "desc": "text"
    },
    {
      "org": "Tesa Tapes India Pvt. Ltd.",
      "desc": "text",
      "start": "October 1993",
      "title": "Product Manager/Application Engineer"
    }
  ],
  "summary": "text blah blah blah"
}
```

I need to access all the values corresponding to keys `start`, `major`, the list of strings from `skills`, `industry`, `org`, `desc` and `summary`, so that I can modify the strings.

So is there some way of accessing the values like this:

```
for keys in outerDict.keys():
    if outerDict[keys] has a nested dict:
        for keys in nestedDict.keys():
            nestedDict[keys] = doStuffToString(nestedDict[keys])
    else:
        outerDict[keys] = doStuffToString(outerDict[keys])
```

In other words, keep indexing the nested dicts (if they exist) until you find a string value.

An even better answer might handle the general case: variable number of dicts nested inside of other dicts. Perhaps there are nested dicts going several layers deep (dicts inside of dicts inside of dicts inside of dicts...until eventually you hit some strings/integers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function.

This function will traverse the dictionary, and when it encounters a list it will traverse every dictionary within that list until it finds whichever key you are looking for. It then changes the value of that entry to new_text:

```py
    def change_all_key_text(input_dict, targ_key, new_text):
        for key, val in input_dict.items():
            if key == targ_key:
                input_dict[key] = new_text
            elif isinstance(val, list):
                for new_dict in val:
                    if isinstance(new_dict, dict):
                        change_all_key_text(new_dict, targ_key, new_text)
```

As per your comment, if you want to change every string, regardless of the key (excluding keys themselves):

```py
def modify_all_strings(input_iterable, new_text):
    if isinstance(input_iterable, dict):
        for key, val in input_iterable.items():
            if isinstance(val, dict) or isinstance(val, list):
                modify_all_strings(val, new_text)
            else:
                # make changes to string here
                input_iterable[key] = new_text
    elif isinstance(input_iterable, list):
        for idx, item in enumerate(input_iterable):
            if isinstance(item, dict) or isinstance(item, list):
                modify_all_strings(item, new_text)
            else:
                # make changes to string here
                input_iterable[idx] = new_text
```

Here you would benefit by adding some structure to the dict. Since the value of each key in the main dict can be either a list of dicts, a string, or a list of strings, there are many input cases that you have to take into account. I'm not sure if you have already learnt about typical [tree data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) or not, but it could help here to make a node class and ensure that each section is a node.

Comment: I think a recursive approach is probably good. What if you don't have a `targ_key`? As in, you want to find any and all strings, and modify those strings, and it doesn't matter what key it belongs to. Or another way of looking at it: imagine this system is like a tree, and the strings are the leaves. You want to find all the leaves, and do something to those leaves (and that something is the same thing for all leaves), but you don't care how you got there, and hence you have no `target leaf`.

Comment: @HumptyDumpty I've updated my solution to include this case as well.